# Filter on a list with headings and keep heading of filtered item(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a data set where each object has a heading and an items array with multiple values. I need to be able to filter on the items while maintaining their heading. The filter component below works without the headings. The data output I want is something like:

If I filter on 'ap...'

Output:

**fruits**

apple

```
const FilterList = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("")
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])

  const data = [
    {
      heading: 'fruits',
      items: [
        { item: 'apple' },
        { item: 'orange' },      
        { item: 'peach' }
      ]
    },
    {
      heading: 'veggies'
      items: [
        { item: 'carrot' },
        { item: 'broccoli' },      
        { item: 'spinach' }, 
      ]
    }
  ]

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let results = []
    if (data && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[0], "heading")) {
      data.forEach(item => {
        results = item.values.filter(value =>
          value.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
        )
      })
      setSearchResults(results)
    }
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder={'placeholder}
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Typography>
        <strong>{heading}</strong>
      </Typography>
      <List>
        {searchResults.map((value, i) => (
          <ListItem key={i}>
            {value.value}
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: do you want multiple headings also? for eg, if there's a veggie starting with `ap` .. how do you want that heading?

Comment: @iamaatoh yes - both headings would display above their respective filtered items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `useEffect` :

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("changed");
    const newSearchResults = data.map(value => ({
      heading: value.heading,
      items: value.items.filter(item => item.item.includes(searchTerm))
    }));
    setSearchResults(newSearchResults);
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

Change your `return` to:

```
return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder={"placeholder"}
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <div>
        {searchResults.map(value => {
          if (value.items.length !== 0) {
            return (
              <>
                <Typography>
                  <strong>{value.heading}</strong>
                </Typography>
                <List>
                  {value.items.map((item, i) => (
                    <ListItem key={i}>{item.item}</ListItem>
                  ))}
                </List>
              </>
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{heading:'fruits',items:[{item:'apple'},{item:'orange'},{item:'peach'}]},{heading:'veggies',items:[{item:'carrot'},{item:'broccoli'},{item:'spinach'},{item: 'peach'}]}]

const filterData = (data, val) => {
  const result = []
  data.forEach(obj => {
    let r = obj.items.filter(item => item.item.includes(val))
    if(r.length > 0) {
      result.push({
        ...obj,
        items: r
      })
    }
  })
  return result
}

console.log(filterData(data, "ap"))
console.log(filterData(data, "pe"))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Created a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-robinson-tvl7d?file=/src/App.js

**Explanation**

In essence, two changes are required:

- need to restructure your `searchResults` to have the same structure as `data`, with `heading` and `items`. Instead of just pushing the items found, we specify the corresponding `heading` also, in the `searchResults` array

```js
// new filtering function
  useEffect(() => {
    const results = [];
    data.forEach(cate => {
      const { heading, items } = cate;

      // remains as is
      const filterdItems = items.filter(item =>
        item.item.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
      );

      // only if filtered items are found
      // add BOTH category & filtered items to results
      if (filterdItems.length) {
        results.push({
          heading,
          items: filterdItems
        });
      }
    });

    setSearchResults(results);
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

- And then, update the `render` block to loop through the categories array and then the items inside each category

```
// updated render
{
 searchResults.map((resultCate, i) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <strong>{resultCate.heading}</strong>
      {resultCate.items.map((item, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>{item.item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
})}
```